# Can I install more than one version of Typescript on a machine?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I'd like to start playing with the latest versions of Typescript but I have production code using 0.82, and I don't want to switch it until I have checked out the new version (we use lots of modules).

Can multiple versions on a machine play nicely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't supported in Visual Studio. Best you could do is just install/uninstall on an as-needed basis.

If you just wanted to try compiling things on the command line, you could use the NPM package and download specific versions that way.

Comment: Yuck! That's disappointing, though understandable given it's not version 1.0 yet.

Comment: Is this still true with TypeScript 1.5 and 1.6?