# What version of TypeScript do Visual Studio 2013 (Update 3) use?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, version, specifications

### What version am I using?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I have Update 3 installed.

There's a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23245395/1268003) that speak of how-to chose TypeScript version, alas I haven't find this "TypeScriptToolsVersion"-entry they speak of anywhere in my files. I have googled for information about which version of TypeScript that Visual Studio use on both internet and the menus of my Visual Studio application but without any results. I must be missing something.

Reason I ask is because in this directory on my computer:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript

..I see TypeScript `0.9` and `1.0` installed. Given that TypeScript was at some point littered with bugs according to my own noble notes from an old TypeScript project, I would like to know which version I am using and if need be, upgrade to the latest.

### Latest version

How do I find out what version of TypeScript is the latest? The TypeScript [website](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) store the [specification file](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) which is as of today versioned 1.0 (2014-10-11).

The website does not list TypeScript compilers that I can download or versions thereof. Instead, the site point me to Visual Studio updates. The "release notes" I could find from Visual Studio Update 3 speak [not a word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933779) about TypeScript versions.

Going back to the TypeScript website, it has a link "[the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript)" which goes to a TypeScript compiler stored on github. In [one of the files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/package.json), I can read that the version of the compiler is `1.3.0` (2014-10-11).

Given that this compiler is linked from the TypeScript website, I guess that it is some form of a "reference implementation" and I can bet my two balls that this is the one Visual Studio is using. Apparently though, the compiler's version `1.3.0` doesn't have anything to do with the version of the *language* TypeScript which I believe is "only" `1.0`.

I've been googling on how-to upgrade the TypeScript version of Visual Studio and that seem to be a smallish nightmare. But my primary goal is to just find out what version of TypeScript I am using. Secondary goal is to understand the versioning scheme a bit better, is the latest version of TypeScript 1.0 or 1.3? Last shall I begin the endeavour of actually upgrading Visual Studio if need be =)

Thank you!

Comment: Run `tsc.exe -v` from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  It is 1.0.3.0 for VS2013 Update 3.

Comment: I can write that command from the regular command prompt as well. I see that the TypeScript 1.0 SDK directory is in my path environment variable. So I'm still not sure what exactly VS (Visual Studio) is using. It should be it, I reason. But can this not be verified somehow? Or are you saying that by using the VS Command Prompt, we get the answer we seek, independent of what the path variable points to? Best of worlds would be if the path variable is what VS is using. Then upgrading my TypeScript compiler will become easy =)

Comment: That's what MSBuild uses.  Visual Studio has its own copy to support IntelliSense, stored in its Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript subdirectory.  Having a mismatch is presumably not that pleasant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But my primary goal is to just find out what version of TypeScript I am using.

Like Hans Passant said `tsc -v` and `where tsc` will guide you to the right path. VS 2013 *is* `1.0.3`

> I guess that it is some form of a "reference implementation" and I can bet my two balls that this is the one Visual Studio is using

If you are looking for the source : https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/tree/release-1.0.3

> Secondary goal is to understand the versioning scheme a bit better, is the latest version of TypeScript 1.0 or 1.3?

`master` is dev branch, completely unstable and not release. (you can use it with tools like `grunt-ts` https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#custom-compiler). So don't worry about the version number there.

Latest release is actually 1.1 CTP (announcement : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/10/06/announcing-typescript-1-1-ctp.aspx source : https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/tree/release-1.1) but as it is CTP you need to fiddle with your VS settings.

The stable is 1.0.3.

## Tip for authoritative answer

Just look at the official blog posts : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, but you can find recent version of TypeScript (1.4) for VS2013 here:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.